# Tensorflow's cycle gan model: error in fit method

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, generative-adversarial-network

I tried to run the code from here: https://keras.io/examples/generative/cyclegan/
but when running model.fit(..) I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Model <__main__.CycleGan object at 0x7fec3de767c0> cannot be saved either because the
input shape is not available or because the forward pass of the model is not defined.To define a 
forward pass, please override `Model.call()`. To specify an input shape, either call 
`build(input_shape)` directly, or call the model on actual data using `Model()`, `Model.fit()`, or 
`Model.predict()`. If you have a custom training step, please make sure to invoke the forward pass
in train step through `Model.__call__`, i.e. `model(inputs)`, as opposed to `model.call()`.
```

Even if I run it through the linked colab file from the author. Did anyone else already faced this issue and knows how to fix it ?
I also tried to predefine the inputsize by model.build((batch_size,256,256,3)), but still get the same error.

If i comment the callbacks, it works. I think the problem is in the `model_checkpoint_callback`. Without it, the code works, but then I don't save the model.

Thanks a lot in advance for every answer!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add this line:

```
# Create cycle gan model
cycle_gan_model = CycleGan(
    generator_G=gen_G, generator_F=gen_F, discriminator_X=disc_X, discriminator_Y=disc_Y
)
# add following line:
cycle_gan_model.compute_output_shape(input_shape=(None, 256, 256, 3))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).